# What is killing JPA query performance in JBoss 7.1.1 (Hibernate 4.x)?

Tags: hibernate, jboss, jpa-2.0

I have a Query which runs fine in JBoss 6.1 (Hibernate 3.6).  It's a simple two table join that returns 955 records.  When I deploy the same .war file in JBoss 7.1.1 the performance suffers dramatically (at least an order of magnitude).  Here is the query:

```
SELECT c.uid, c.name, -1, c.file_Id, cs.error, cs.is_Error, c.parent_Uid, c.job_Id, c.description 
FROM stage.Classification_Status cs, stage.Classification c 
WHERE cs.is_Error = true AND cs.classification_Id = c.id AND c.job_Id = 3001;
```

I haven't been able to tell which version of Hibernate is bundled in JBoss 7.1.1 so I don't know which verion to file a bug against.

Has anyone else seen this kind of performance hit moving from Hibernate 3.6 to 4.x?  Any ideas what is causing it?

Comment: I assume the same query is generated on both servers? If the same SQL query is sent, the result must be somewhere on the higher level. Incorrectly configured `DataSource`/lack of pooling or no caching? Maybe N+1 problem somehow occurred? Are you sure no extra traffic is sent to the database? Have you tried profiling?

Comment: The time is spent in query.getResultList().  I've taken the Hibernate generated query from JBoss 7.1 (which has the performance problem) and run it directly against the same database and that query returns with 955 results immediately.  It's not the generated query, it's what JBoss 7 / Hibernate 4.x is doing with the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Are you logging too much?

Because that's really take time, so if you do not log, the performance will be better.

I have a servlet with just one log call, that according to Firebug/Firefox, **responds in 1 ms** without logging, 2 ms logging in file only, 3 ms logging in file and console. **And 1,270 ms** when I log 955 times!

Those logging's times are the best ones from many tries, but are not to often. For the other side, the 1ms without logging happens more often.